# Extend contact form validation PHP script with some error messages

Tags: php, forms, validation, contacts

Below is the code for a contact form validation script that I would like to extend.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: DaVv'; 
    $to = 'mail@mail.com'; 
    $subject = 'The topic';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit'] {               
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>
```

I want to add one more message for user about email, something like: "Please enter valid email address." when, for example, they do not write "@". I know that this is included in html 5 but I'd like to make this w/o HTML5.

Comment: You mean `client-side` validation ?

Comment: js validation ?? or php side validation ?

Comment: js validation: use frameworks. php validation: use `regexp` and reffer to regexp library for email, phone, strings, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: DaVv'; 
    $to = 'mail@mail.com'; 
    $subject = 'The topic';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)
        {               
            if(mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from))
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            else
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
        else
            echo '<p>Wrong Email</p>';

    }
    else if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

These links may help you for email validation

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve but I'm assuming it's server side validation for an e-mailaddress?

If so you could use the following PHP snippet:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // The user supplied an invalid e-mailaddress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys i wrote wrong code previously (coz i was in work)

this is the correct:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: domain.com'; 
$to = 'dawid@main.com'; 
$subject = 'Message from domain.com';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
   if ($name != '' && $email != '') {                
      if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
         echo '<p class="msg">Your message has been sent!</p>';
      } else { 
         echo '<p class="msg">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
      } 
             } else {
                 echo '<p class="msg">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
             }
  }
?>
```

And to this i would like to add email validation (SERVER SIDE) and msg "u wrote wrong email" or sth like that... but i dont wanna delete any of the messages which are included now in the contact form. Just wanna add info about wrong email.

Thanks for help once more ;)

Comment: and also i'd like to display just one "error message" even if there would be for example "not all fields filled" and "wrong email" i'd like to display just one error from these two (that's an example)